# read external json file firestore cloud function

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

Is there a way to read a json file form another api/server?

I want to store it and using another function, import that json into firestore every 24 hours with a cron or something.

please help me, I don't have a lot of experience using javascript

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const request = require('request');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
const serviceAccount = require("./service-key.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    databaseURL: "****"
});

exports.helloWorld = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
 response.send("Hello from Firebase!");
});

exports.getEvents = functions.https.onRequest(() => {
    var data = request.get('https://****', res => {
            console.log(res);
        }
    )
});
```

Comment: Yes it is possible

Comment: but how? I'm trying to look for an answer but none of them work

Comment: update your Question and show what you do already

Comment: You're going to have to be a lot more specific about what you mean by "another api/server".  This could mean just about anything.

Comment: I want to fetch a json from another non google server that I have and store it into a variable just to begin.